# AWS RDS MariaDB update from 10.2 to 10.3 now has slowed my queries

Tags: index, mariadb, partitioning, amazon-rds

This AWS RDS MariaDB server has been running for 5+years now.

After the automatic Amazon RDS update from **10.2** to **10.3**, the server had downtime (during the update), then after it went online, the ***read IOPS*** went from **196**, up to **6000**. the script that runs this query was unchanged, the data on this table was virtually the same (*supposedly, if the update did not mess anything up*).

This is draining the resources of the RDS instance and has caused a budget issue (*Storage type is Provisioned IOPS)*, the ***read IOPS*** are steady at 6000 while this script is running, it queries a HUGE table `"table_x"` which is partitioned into 8 by `**RANGE**` of the `YEAR` field of the row.

Does anyone know why this huge performance impact since the update? May the partitions have anything to do with it? Is there a way to check if the indexes of this table are working properly?

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_x` (
  `mac` char(12) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mac`,`timestamp`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
 PARTITION BY RANGE (year(`timestamp`))
(PARTITION `p2010` VALUES LESS THAN (2011) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p2011` VALUES LESS THAN (2012) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p2012` VALUES LESS THAN (2013) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p2013` VALUES LESS THAN (2014) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p2014` VALUES LESS THAN (2015) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `p2015` VALUES LESS THAN (2016) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION `current` VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB);
```

These are the partition info for the current table:

```
  Partition Type    Expression          Rows        IndexLength
    p2010   RANGE   year(`timestamp`)   360856      9199616
    p2011   RANGE   year(`timestamp`)   4599590     108527616
    p2012   RANGE   year(`timestamp`)   42523149    970981376
    p2013   RANGE   year(`timestamp`)   143304668   3212304384
    p2014   RANGE   year(`timestamp`)   246257944   5246009344
    p2015   RANGE   year(`timestamp`)   335840833   9929998336
    current RANGE   year(`timestamp`)   4166357922  92812574720
```

Any query on this table for this years data, will take around 15 minutes to return. Before the update it took around 5 seconds. This particular query uses `NOW()` function to calculate current date, so query caching is off the table.

Query:

```
SELECT  subscriber.*
    FROM  subscriber
    INNER JOIN  billing ON subscriber.mac = billing.station_mac
    INNER JOIN  
    (
        SELECT mac, MAX(timestamp) as maxts
            FROM table_x
            GROUP BY mac
            HAVING  maxts > date_sub(NOW(),INTERVAL 48 HOUR) 
    ) as innerquery  ON innerquery.mac = subscriber.mac
    WHERE  subscriber.type = 'Type1'
      AND  subscriber.deleted = 0
      AND  subscriber.suspended = 0
      AND  billing.next_renewal > NOW()
    ORDER BY mac
```

Explain SELECT:

```
1   PRIMARY subscriber  ref mac_type,type   type    63  const   1   Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY billing eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 152 db.subscriber.mac   1   Using where
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ref key0    key0    36  db.subscriber.mac   4   Using where
2   LATERAL DERIVED table_x ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 36  db.subscriber.mac   44  Using where; Using index
```

Ive been thinking of adding more partitions, but this is the current structure that it had before the update and it was working fine.

Comment: An example query with the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE ` would be helpful. You're probably getting different query plans now. Note `PARTITION`ing is not really a tool for improving read performance.

Comment: Show us the query.  And `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  Even "5 seconds" does not make sense.  Are you using `LIKE` with a leading wildcard?  Or some kind of range?  What?

Comment: @RickJames i will post the explain, but youre missing the point, before the update, the query took only seconds to complete, after the update, it takes 15min, the query hasnt changed, neither has the network load, only the mariadb version changed from 10.2 to 10.3

Comment: @FernandoPérez No Rick isn't missing the point though. 5 seconds is slow enough to likely indicate an underlying problem that was always there but tolerable enough that you never realized or investigated. When database systems change versions, generally their engines change (usually for the better) with how they analyze and execute queries. When a query had an underlying problem already, sometimes that issue gets exasperated due to these database engine changes. That seems like a very possible scenario for what you're facing (though not necessarily conclusively). Hard to say without `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: @J.D. Hi! Thanks for the input, however 5sec on 300billion rows seems like a good output, i will paste the EXPLAIN soon :) thanks!

Comment: @J.D. ive added the EXPLAIN and ive removed the contact JOIN which was not necessary <3

Comment: @FernandoPérez No prob! I know 5s for a **total** data size of 300 billion rows seems good but if your queries and database are architected correctly, it shouldn't need to scan through **all** 300 billion. A B-Tree index is `O(log(n))` which for 300 billion rows is `log(300 billion) = ~39` (roughly speaking, there's a fanout factor that makes this number potentially smaller). That means with proper index seeks, your query should only have to traverse 39 nodes at most to find your data. 5 seconds to do that indicates there may be a problem. (This is why `PARTITIONING` isn't a performance tool.)

Comment: @J.D. ive put up the EXPLAIN section, care to have  alook at it :)

Comment: `maxts` is computed but not used.  What is the intent of doing that JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

I suspect that the pig partition is bigger than the buffer pool *and* the query is doing a full scan of that partition.

Before the partition was that big, it could do the scan without hitting the disk.  Then (perhaps "suddenly"), the query was completely I/O-bound.  That *could* explain the 5s -> 15m.  I often see 10x slowdown; you are seeing a 180x slowdown, so there may be something else going on.  Is the disk SSD?  Or HDD?

The one table you provided does not seem to match any of the 4 tables in the query.  I need to see the datatypes, indexes, etc for each of the tables.  The `EXPLAIN SELECT` would help with partitions, index usage, order of using the tables (I hope it starts with the derived table), etc.  The HAVING looks strange; I'll look for issues with it on 10.3.

Please qualify each column with the table it is in.  It could make a big difference in which table `deleted` and `suspended` are.

Are the tables 1:1 or 1:many and in which direction?

Tentatively, this is likely to help.

```
tablex:  INDEX(oid, timestamp)
```

Does the query actually use anything from `contact` and `billing`?  If not those `JOINs` could be a burden.

Which is more selective?  max_ts > 2 days ago?  Or next_renewal > now?

Comment: The RDS server uses 8000 Provisioned IOPS EB Storage

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G

Answer (score 0):

We had a very similar thing happen recently, going from 10.2 to 10.3.

The two things that made a big difference where:

1. Changing `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` to be `2` instead of `1` (`0` would also work). More details on that parameter [here](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit/)
2. Changing `sync_binlog` to `0`. More info [here](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/sync_binlog/). Note that using `0` will *not* be preferable in some circumstances. So I would read up on that a bit more